# How to checkin recently added files to tfs 2013 (Workspace.CheckIn())?

Tags: .net

Good day. 
I try to checkin files into TFS using [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb139039.aspx) method. Msdn (link above) talks: "However, this operation is not valid if any pending changes in the workspace are edits or adds, because content will not have been uploaded to the server."
So, what method can I use instead of Workspace.Checkin(), or how can I upload this files to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I used syntax

```
ws.CheckIn(null, @"domain\user", "comment", null, null, null);
```

If you use null as the first argument - you checkin all, but can't checkin 'Add' or 'Edit' pendings. 
Right syntax for the checkin with 'Add' or\and 'Edit' pendings:

```
ws.CheckIn(ws.GetPendingChanges(), @"domain\user", "comment", null, null, null);
```

This code checkin all pendings.